# Перехват исключений в argparse

Tags: python, исключения, argparse

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="путь к файлу", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="путь выходного файла", required=False)
parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", help="действие над файлом", required=True, choices=["r2c", "c2r"])
parser.add_argument("-q", "--quit", help="если указать, программа не укажет ошибки", required=False,
                        action='store_true')
    
args = parser.parse_args()
```

флаг `-а` должен быть обязательным, но при этом, если указать `-q`, то `"error: the following arguments are required: -a/--action"` выводится не должно. Подскажите, возможно ли это сделать?

Пробовал через обычный `try-except`  - не помогло. Пробовал  `try-except SystemExit`, тоже не получилось. Ещё попробовал `try-except BaseException` - всё бесполезно. Предполагаю, что это из-за того, что исключение ловится в библиотеке argparse, но как это решить  - не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `ArgumentParser` есть параметр [`exit_on_error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#exit-on-error), но он влияет не на все варианты ошибок, в частности при незаполненных обязательных аргументах программа все равно принудительно завершается.

Я посмотрел исходники `argparse`, вариант решения такой: отнаследоваться от `ArgumentParser` и переопределить метод `error`, чтобы он бросал исключение с сообщением об ошибке, а не вызывал `exit`. Это вполне допустимый вариант, тем более что в докстроке к `exit` явно упоминается переопределение этого метода:

```
    def error(self, message):
        """error(message: string)

        Prints a usage message incorporating the message to stderr and
        exits.

        If you override this in a subclass, it should not return -- it
        should either exit or raise an exception.
        """
        self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
        args = {'prog': self.prog, 'message': message}
        self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
```

Смысл такой, что при переопределении метода он должен завершаться либо бросанием исключения, либо выходом из программы. Вот и заменим выход из программы на выбрасывание исключения.

Рабочий код:

```
import argparse


class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super().__init__(message)


class NoExitArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        raise MyException(message)


parser = NoExitArgumentParser()
    
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="путь к файлу", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="путь выходного файла", required=False)
parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", help="действие над файлом", required=True, choices=["r2c", "c2r"])
parser.add_argument("-q", "--quit", help="если указать, программа не укажет ошибки", required=False,
                        action='store_true')


try:
    parser.parse_args()
except MyException as ex:
    print("Catched exception")
    parser.print_usage()
    print(str(ex))


print("Hello")
```

Вывод при запуске без параметров:

```
Catched exception
usage: test_arparse.py [-h] -i INPUT [-o OUTPUT] -a {r2c,c2r} [-q]
the following arguments are required: -i/--input, -a/--action
Hello
```

Чтобы не показывать ошибки при включенном аргументе `-q`, можно не выбрасывать ошибки, а сохранять их в список, но 100% работоспособность класса при таком варианте я уже не гарантирую:

```
import argparse


class NoExitArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.errors = []

    def error(self, message):
        self.errors.append(message)


parser = NoExitArgumentParser()
    
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="путь к файлу", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="путь выходного файла", required=False)
parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", help="действие над файлом", required=True, choices=["r2c", "c2r"])
parser.add_argument("-q", "--quit", help="если указать, программа не укажет ошибки", required=False,
                        action='store_true')


args = parser.parse_args()
if parser.errors:
    if args.quit:
        pass
    else:
        parser.print_usage()
        for error in parser.errors:
            print(error)


print("Hello")
```

Comment: спасибо, но я так понимаю, это работает всегда, даже если не указывать -q из-за того, что ошибка перехватывается там, где определяются аргументы парсера? значит с этим условием сделать не получится?

Comment: @артемкостриков как вариант тогда не выбрасывать исключение, а сохранять ошибку в список, но работоспособность класса при таком варианте не гарантирую. Добавил пример.

Comment: @артемкостриков можно еще попробовать использовать альтернативные парсеры аргументов (например, [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com)), возможно там как-то более гибко можно настроить.

Comment: благодарю, очень помогло